# Javascript split not working in Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to JS and Vue. I have a Vue application where I am getting the date from an open api. I am trying to get the date only from the api and the requested resource(which is, for example, `2019-10-15T09:17:11.808545+02:00`)  contains both date and time. I am unable to split the date from the time at "TO" and would appreciate some help in this regard. This is what I have:

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        {{split_date(this.date)}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            axios.get("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin", {})
                .then(response => {
                    this.date = response.data.datetime;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },

        data() {
            return {
                date: "",
                separated_date: [],
            };
        },

        methods: {
            split_date(date) {
                this.separated_date = date.split("TO");
                return this.separated_date[0];
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The output I get is the whole returned response: `2019-10-15T09:17:11.808545+02:00`

I also get the error: `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

Comment: It isn't `TO`, it's just `T`. Your time starts with a `0`, number zero.

Comment: Why don't you use `momentjs` ?

Comment: This does nt have to do anything with vue.js  if you use split of 'T0' (zero) instead of 'O' letter you will get the actual expected result

Comment: @SagarJajoriya it just happens to be more secure for my Vue application at least :D but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The infinite update loop is because you create a reactive dependency on `separated_date` inside `split_date` and then update the property value. Each time it renders it'll update that value with a new array, causing it to render again. I suggest using a computed property instead of a method and removing `separated_date` from the `data` entirely.

Comment: @skirtle I added the method in Computed and removed separated_date from data, but then I get ```TypeError: date.split is not a function```

Comment: @AlyssaAlex you should convert incoming date time value to date object. then use javascript date methods rather than using the split. Also you can use momentJS to manipulate date time objects easily.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to a computed property. It needs to read `date` from `this.date`. Something like `return this.date.split('T')[0]`.

Comment: @skirtle this is what I did

`computed: {
    split_date() {
      var separated_date = this.date.split("T");
      return separated_date[0];
    }
  }`
and called it, like `{{split_date()}}`

Comment: That is not how you call a computed property. It's a property, not a method. It should be just `{{ split_date }}`.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! @skirtle

Answer (score 0):

Like others said in the comments, you're splitting on `TO` while you should be splitting on `T`. Your time starts with `0` (zero number). Also, you don't need to save the `separated_date` inside the `data`-property. You could use [a computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to automatically recalculate the `separated_date` when the original date changes.

Just a note: if you're doing lots of stuff with date(time)s, it's not the worst idea to use a library to help you. Popular libraries are for example [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), or [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com)

Answer (score -1):

This is not really a Vue problem, but a JS date/time handling/parsing question:

```js
const date = new Date('2019-10-15T09:17:11.808545+02:00')

console.log("Date object:", date)

// example date elements:
console.log("Year:", date.getFullYear())
console.log("Month:", date.getMonth() + 1) // JS starts numbering months from 0
console.log("Timestamp:", date.getTime())

// to get YYYY-MM-DD, with leading zeroes
const datetime = `${date.getFullYear()}-${("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}`

console.log("YYYY-MM-DD:", datetime)
```

You can read about **Date** here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

**Solution**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    split_date: ''
  },
  methods: {
    async getWorldTime() {
      const resp = await fetch('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Berlin')
      const worldTime = await resp.json()
      return await worldTime.datetime
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    console.log(await this.getWorldTime())
    const date = new Date(await this.getWorldTime())
    this.split_date = `${date.getFullYear()}-${("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}`
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{split_date}}</div>
```